# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found while printing beam.PCollection

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm trying to print a beam.PCollection and I'm a bit puzzled why it does not work.

I have one collections consisting out of 2 elements with 2 different keys (col1):

```
('Key2',
 ['file:///Users/DiesDas.txt'])
('Key3',
 ['file:///Users/DiesDas2.txt'])
```

which I can print using `beam.Map(print)`

And a second one (col2):

```
('Key2',
 ['DiesDas1.csv'])

('Key3',
 ['DiesDas2.csv'])
```

Which I can also print

Calling

```
grouped = (
    col1,
    col2,
) >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
```

works fine, however

```
grouped = (
    col1,
    col2,
) >> beam.CoGroupByKey() | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
```

Fails with `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`

Any ideas what could be the issue or how to best debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a set of brackets in your last statement. Executing this on [play.beam.apache.org](https://play.beam.apache.org) works as expected:

```
import apache_beam as beam
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  col1 = (
    pipeline
    | 'Create col1' >> beam.Create([
      ('Key2', ['file:///Users/DiesDas.txt']),
      ('Key3', ['file:///Users/DiesDas2.txt'])
    ])
  )

  col2 = (
    pipeline
    | 'Create col2' >> beam.Create([
      ('Key2', ['DiesDas1.csv']),
      ('Key3', ['DiesDas2.csv'])
    ])
  )

  grouped = (  # missing opening bracket
    (col1, col2)
    | "merge" >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
    | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
  )  # missing closing bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError explains the issue actually, beaMap  requires you to string but you are suppyling tuple. Would suggest checking library docs for allowed inputs.

Comment: The 2 collections I'm trying to group are also tuples (of the key a list)
They can be printed just fine.
I dont see why the result of the operation (which finishes just fine) of the 2 collections I can print cant be printed.